# Change back to original json structure in swift

Tags: javascript, ios, json, swift

I have passed a stringily json object from javascript to swift.

**js**

```
'use strict';

var labdetail = function()
{
var labs = ["sdsdsd","suds","DH-sdsd","DH-sdsd"]
var labgrp = {labGrp:"R", labGrpDesc:"sdsd",labs:labs}
var labGroups = []
labGroups[0] = labgrp
var labs1 = ["dsdsd","suds","DH-sdsd","DH-dfdf]
var labgrp1 = {labGrp:"H", labGrpDesc:"dfdf",labs:labs}
labGroups[1] = labgrp1
return JSON.stringify(labGroups);

}
```

**swift**

```
import UIKit
import JavaScriptCore
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let context = JSContext()
    let returnLabResultJSPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("returnLabResult", ofType: "js")
    let contentData = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(returnLabResultJSPath!)
    let content = NSString(data: contentData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String
   //     let returnresult = try String(contentsOfFile: returnLabResultJSPath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    context.evaluateScript(content)
    let getlabfunction =  context.objectForKeyedSubscript("labdetail")
    var labresult = getlabfunction.callWithArguments([])
    let labresultdict :dictionary = labresult.toDictionary()

    print(labresult)

}
```

I want to change it back as the original structure. I try to use `todictionary()` but fail

Now the result of lab result is 
[{"labGrp":"R","labGrpDesc":"sad sad","labs":["sad sad","asdasd","sadsad-sadsa","DH-asdasd"]},{"labGrp":"H","labGrpDesc":"Biology","labs":["asdsad","asdsad","and","DH-asdasd"]}]

i want it to be an array,and array[0] contains {"labGrp":"R","labGrpDesc":"sad sad","labs":["sad sad","asdasd","sadsad-sadsa","DH-asdasd"]}

and array[1] contains  {"labGrp":"H","labGrpDesc":"Biology","labs":["asdsad","asdsad","and","DH-asdasd"]}

Comment: what do you need really .. **i want to change it back as the original structure**?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, You need to **deserialise the JSon object** then it results the `Dictionary` object .

Ex:

```
      var labresult = getlabfunction.callWithArguments([])

        do{
            if let data = labresult.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? [String:String]
          }catch{  }
```

Comment: value of type 'JSValue' has no member 'dataUsingEncoding'

Comment: Yes. thats right and the JS function returning a JSon object deserialising the  JSon object solves ur problem.... Find a way  'labresult ' to data ... Anti solves ur problem ...

Comment: labresult should be string?

Comment: I never worked on JSContext. Check what content u r receiving and make that too NSData n use the above to deserialise .